# Reading from CSV, converting to JSON and storing in MongoDB

Tags: python, json, pandas, mongodb, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file in Pandas, convert each row in to a JSON object and append them to a dict and then store in MongoDB.

Here is my code

```
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('data/airports_test.csv'))

for i in data.index:
    json = data.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
    json_dict = json.to_dict()

print(json_dict[5])

ins = collection.insert_many(json_dict)
# for i in json_dict:
#     ins = collection.insert_one(json_dict[i])
```

If I print elements of the dict I get the correct output (I think..). If I try to use collection.insert_many, I get the error `'documents must be a non empty list'` If I try to loop through the dict and add one at a time I get the error

`document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping`

I have Googled and Googled but I can't seem to find a solution! Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what the overall problem is here, but you overwrite your `json_dict` variable in every loop so by the time the loop exits, you have only your last dataframe row in the dictionary and nothing else. At any rate, why not just use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was unsure of how to implement to_dict but I have tried it both inside and out of the loop with the same results. When I use DataFrame.to_json I get each column as an object rather than each row, which is what I was aiming for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip processing the individual rows of the DataFrame via:

```py
import json
import pandas
data = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.read_csv('test2.csv'))
data = data.to_dict(orient="records")
collection.insert_many(data)
```

As an aside, I think I would personally use the `csv` module and `dictReader` rather than `pandas` here but this way is fine.

Comment: Sorry I have tried that and I still get the document must be an instance of dict error

Comment: `insert_many()`

Comment: ugg sorry, `pymongo` wants to work with an actual array of dicts not json text.  let me fix it.